# lpthread libary difference between Solaris and GNU/Linux when linking with gcc

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, gcc, solaris

In Linux(Debian 7), when I run the server, the pointer to array *arg for *doSomething it crashes with segmentation fault. 
(Line `int *arg = malloc(sizeof(*arg));`)
When I run the same code in Solaris, it runs like a charm.
Everything is compiled at its own respective OS (running at Solaris, compiled at Solaris, etc) with no errors or warnings.
A code snippet of the main body of the server without the doSomething method

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     int sockfd, portno,pErr;
     socklen_t clilen;
     //char buffer[256];
     //char servPlay[10];

     struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
     int n;
     if (argc < 2) {
         fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no port provided\n");
         exit(1);
     }
     sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
     if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR opening socket");
     bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
     portno = atoi(argv[1]);
     serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
     serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
     serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
     if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
              error("ERROR on binding");
      while(1) {
        int newsockfd;
        printf("Listening\n");
        listen(sockfd,5);
        clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
        newsockfd = accept(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
        if (newsockfd < 0) 
            error("ERROR on accept");
        printf("Client %s connected\n", inet_ntoa(cli_addr.sin_addr));
        int *arg = malloc(sizeof(*arg));
        if(arg ==NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "No memory for thread\n");
        }
        *arg=newsockfd;
        pErr = pthread_create(NULL,NULL,doSomething,arg);
        if(pErr!=0)
        {
            error("Cannot cread thread\n");
            //break;
            }
        }
     close(sockfd);
     return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Even if you can point me to the direction of lpthread library source for solaris and for linux, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: If it crashes in the call to `malloc` it should have nothing to do with the pthread library. However, you might want to alter your code so you don't use the `arg` variable if the `malloc` call failes (returns `NULL`), right now if the allocation fails you just print an error message, but will still continue to dereference the (`NULL`) pointer.

Comment: You're right, I haven't realized that I actually continued using the null pointed. But this raises another question, why I can allocate memory when I run it in Solaris, but it doesn't allocate when in Linux?

Comment: It could be as simple as there not being any memory available? Or not a big enough block to map? When does this problem happen? On the first connection? After X connections?

Comment: It happens on the first connection.

Comment: So you should, in theory, have plenty of free memory?

Comment: There should be plenty of memory.  Let me clarify things a bit;

Comment: There should be plenty of memory.  Let me clarify things a bit;
In solaris or linux, I connect from a thin client to a Solaris or linux server respectively. So everything beyond my permission level (like memory management, among other things) is out of my reach. So I can only rely on what info I get from commands and everything seems fine. But until now no such problem has ever occured, even though I have made use of malloc(in the linux server mostly) in other c programs as well.

Comment: The first `NULL` argument to `pthread_create()` seems suspect. Maybe some systems allow passing a `NULL` `pthread_t*` to `pthread_create`, but I wouldn't bank on this to be portable.

Answer (score 1):

More probably than not mnunberg hit the mark and the crash happens in `pthread_create()` rather than the line you think.

`man pthread_create`:

> Before returning, a successful call to **pthread_create()** stores  the 
>   ID of  the  new thread in the buffer pointed to by *thread*; this identifier
>          is used to refer to the thread in subsequent calls  to  other  pthreads
>          functions.

It would be pointless allowing to pass a NULL pointer as the first argument (*thread*).